# Inline form twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for asking such an easy question but how can i make a form like this **inline**?

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="field">
      <label>test</label> 
      <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">  
  </div>

  <div class="field">
      <label>test</label> 
      <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">  
  </div>

  <div class="field">
      <label>test</label>  
      <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>  
</form>
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtPdz/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.field {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/rtPdz/2/

The reason, very short and friendly, is that `div`s are block level elements and by default have their `display` property set to `block`, which occupy all the width available to them in the document flow context that they are located in. To change that behavior one way is to change the default `display` value of `block` to `inline-block`.

> **block**:
>       This value causes an element to generate a block box.
>
> **inline-block**:
>       This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box,
>   and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.

Read more on the `display` property: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display

Comment: Small explanation of block vs inline might be in order here - perhaps `div` vs `span` for example.

Comment: @BillyMoon Agreed, added some short explanation.

Comment: **+1** Nicely explained answer =)